# Unable to output useState to imported chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form where i will add a task and add the amount of minutes that task has taken, i am having trouble trying to get the chart which i have imported from 'Recharts' to see the state, it looks like the state is returning an empty array and my chart is not seeing the data.

The Recharts chart takes an array with an object inside with two values, example shown below

```
const data = [
    { name: "Group A", data: 400 },
    { name: "Group B", data: 300 },
    { name: "Group C", data: 300 },
    { name: "Group D", data: 200 },
    { name: "Group E", data: 278 },
    { name: "Test Data", data: 189 }
  ];
```

However after i have moved my state as props to the component and mapped the result to take the same names as input the charts is not displaying anything
(my mapped props)

```
const activityData = [
    ...props.pieData.map(el => ({
      name: el.title,
      data: el.amount
    }))
  ];
```

I have put a simplified version on codesandbox to make it a little bit easier if anyone wants to see the output i'm getting
https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-dew-676xc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue as soon as i posted this, the 'data' value which i had mapped in my props was getting outputted as a string, when the object was expecting a number